# Can't remove or rename file

Tags: java, delete-file

I am trying to remove the last line of a CVS file, to do so I need to rename / delete my input file, I tried several things, but I can't get it to work, this is what I got now:

```
File inputFile = new File((file.getParent() + "/ExportLijst " +  dateFormat.format(date) + ".csv"));
inputFile.setWritable(true, true);
File f = (inputFile);

if (!f.exists())
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      "Delete: no such file or directory: " + inputFile);

if (!f.canWrite())
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: write protected: "
      + inputFile);


if (f.isDirectory()) {
  String[] files = f.list();
  if (files.length > 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Delete: directory not empty: " + inputFile);
}

boolean success = f.renameTo(removeFile);

if (!success)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: deletion failed");
```

I also tried this, with no result:

```
public void forceRename(File source, File target) throws IOException
{
   if (target.exists())
     target.delete();
   source.renameTo(target);
}
```

Comment: Do you create this file from code? Haven't you forgotten to close the writing streams? (It is considered locked until the stream is open so you cannot delete it.)

Comment: are you doing this in windows OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you did not **close** the file, and then the other file operations will not do on Windows.

The code snippets you have put together for us, are in this way not very coherent - of course.
They look fine, though one would need to see the context. A bit much.

So try ensuring a close:

```
try (PrintWriter csvOut = ...) {
    ...
} // Automatic close
```